# Multiplying big Theta?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

[image]

Im doing some practice problems and I'm confused by this question. Where did O(n^2.5) come from? Are they multiplying the big theta somehow? I'm lost.

Comment: Be careful, this is "big theta", not "big O"

Comment: Oops, thank you! Made an edit

Comment: Wouldn't this be more suitable for Math.SE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about it this way: `(x*y)*(x/y)` is `x^2`, right? And `sqrt(x)` is `x^0.5`. So add the exponents together and you get `x^2.5`.

In the first case, the `log n` can be simplified out, as it is both multiplied and divided by.

Comment: Sorry, i'm still confused how they came to the final answer. Am I treating the red part as (n log(n))*(sqrt(n))*(n/log(n))? And simplifying?

Comment: @user239435 You just multiply everything inside the big Theta together, and then simplify.